# Another word for "gain" when talking about subscribers

Tags: synonyms

Difficult to explain and I'm not sure such concept does exist but here's the question - suppose we're talking about a facebook page and we want to artificcially increase the number of subscribers by any mean possible (including black hat tactics). What kind of word should we use instead of just 'gain'?
To be more clear - in Russian language such word has a meaning which is opposite to "rewinding" odometer of your car - it would have been used to decribe when someone would rather add some milage to his car with certain tools.
Or can we just say "subscriber fraud" or something?

Comment: Something like "inflate the subscriber count" has a connotation of using sneaky tactics.

Comment: I'll make it an answer then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inflate the subscriber count** has a connotation of using sneaky tactics.

**[Inflate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inflate)**:

> 2. Increase (something) by a large or excessive amount.
>
>    2.1 Exaggerate

See also [google results](http://www.google.com/search?q="inflate+the+subscriber+count")

Comment: There's also "boost the subscriber count"

Comment: @SovereignSun, "boost" would normally be assumed to involve legitimate means.  "Grow" subscribers would be another such word.  However, the OP is specifically looking for a word that implies nefarious tactics, so "boost" wouldn't be good for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Jack up the subscriber count** would indicate the artificial increase beyond the real value, although it is usually temporary or incremental in nature.

[jack up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jack+up):

> Raise or increase, as in The cartel is jacking up oil prices again. This term alludes to the literal meaning of jack up, that is, "hoist with a jack."